# How to make postgresql only record DDL statement in logs?

Tags: postgresql

I want **only** DDL statements in postgresql logs.

I have set `log_statement` to `ddl`， and changed log_min_messages to 'log'，but I still got log like this:

```
< 2018-05-15 05:10:25.078 EDT > LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled  
< 2018-05-15 05:10:25.079 EDT > LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections  
< 2018-05-15 05:10:25.085 EDT > LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
```

I want only DDL statements because I want to generate DDL patch from log to synchronize database in production environment.
Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look into https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit
or if you ant to code it, consider using https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html

eg:

```
so=# create or replace function notice_ddl() returns event_trigger as $$
begin
raise info '%', session_user || ' ran '||tg_tag||' '||current_query();
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
so=# create or replace function notice_ddl() returns event_trigger as $$
begin
raise info '%', session_user || ':: ran "'||tg_tag||'" ('||current_query()||')';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
so=# create event trigger etg on ddl_command_start execute procedure notice_ddl();
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER
so=# create table so(i int);
INFO:  vao:: ran "CREATE TABLE" (create table so(i int);)
CREATE TABLE
```

surely you can save statement to table of notify channel instead of rasing info...

also if you want to use postgres logs, [look into csv logs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-LOGGING-CSVLOG)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19731893)

Comment: @jrtapsell added simple example

Comment: csv log does't work since it log the same thing as stderr

Comment: @Tim with difference, that you can extremely easily import csv to database and very effectively query it. instead of regexping logs with bash or so...